# Differential Equation on a Pointlike Region

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Lets say we have a region $[-a,a]$ on the real axis. On that region we define some non-trivial differential equation:

$$\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}y(x)\right)^2 = f(y(x))$$

with $x\in [-a,a]$. Now, if we take $a \rightarrow 0$ the region will shrink until the only available value for $x$ becomes $x\equiv 0$. How can I evaluate the differential equation at hand in this special case? Should I simply demand $f(y(0))=0$ ? I am looking for the logic behind the math in such cases in general.

Answer (score 1):

A differential equation on a region consisting of a single point doesn't make any sense.  You should be looking at the differential equation when $a > 0$, computing whatever you need to there, and then you can study limits of those quantities as 
$a \to 0+$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have been thinking about it the last few minutes and realized that a differential equation always has boundary conditions. If $f(y(-a))=f(y(a))=const.$ is demanded, I guess that will be the value of $f(y(0))$ after $a \rightarrow 0$. If both boundaries are different, it gets complicated...

Answer (score 0):

In general you need an open subset of $R$ to talk about derivatives in the classical sense.  An open set needs to have a neighborhood around each point meaning that it is never a single point.